# Flex Text Input with icon inside like mac os x search text input

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, textinput

I'm trying to extend the text input that comes in flex to support an icon, just like mac os x search text input has a grey circle aligned to the right, the text input has a addChild method, but it didn't work for me.

Is there some way to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution :D here it's the code

The trick was override the updateDisplayList.

Happy hacking.

```
package
{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

import mx.controls.Image;
import mx.controls.TextInput;
import mx.core.mx_internal;

use namespace mx_internal;

public class MyTextInput extends TextInput
{
    private var _image:Image;

    public function MyTextInput()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();

        _image = new Image();
        _image.source = "http://sstatic.net/so/img/replies-off.png",

        addChild(DisplayObject(_image));
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        this._image.width = 16;
        this._image.height = 16;

        this._image.x = this.width - this._image.width - 5;
        this._image.y = this.height - this._image.height;

        this.textField.width = this.width - this._image.width - 5;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this would be to create an mxml component that looks like the text input you want. I've never seen the mac OSX search box, but based on your description a component based off the canvas with a white back ground, and proper boarders could then contain an image and a text input without boarders. This would give you the look you're going for I think.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that workaround, because if we change the styles for the text inputs I don't want to go to that component and recreate the style and spend hours trying to give the canvas the appropriate look & feel, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: I can appreciate that, but understand that this is not a workaround; this is what flex is designed to do. In fact if you do this one time, using the gui design mode of flex builder it will actually make this easier to update and make changes to.